Does $\sin(n/x)$ converges a.e. to a constant?
Let us consider the sequence of functions $\sin(n/x)$, for $x\in(0,1)$.
Is it true that there exists a subsequence $n_j$ such that $\sin({n_j}/x)\to 0$ a.e.?
Intuitively, my guess is yes. For every $\varepsilon>0$, fixed $x\in(0,1)$, we can always find a subsequence $n_{j(x)}$ such that $|\sin(n_{j(x)}/x)|\le \varepsilon$. So, one has that $\sin(n_{j(x)}/x)\to 0$. The question is how to avoid the dependence of the subsequence on $x$. My idea is to use a diagonal argument on the point $x$ and the subsequence $j(x)$, but I'm not sure that it works.
Any comments are welcome!

For $x=\frac 2 \pi \in [0,1]$, can you tell me $\sin(n/x)$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$? Can you spot the pattern?

Yes, of course is the first thing that one notes. But I'm interested in a.e. convergence! You can consider $n\in \mathbb{R}$ if you want.

$n\in \mathbb{R}$ would make things worse.  You get occasional convergence for integer $n$, for example if $x= \frac1{k\pi}$ for some integer $k$, but in general you do not get convergence.  Can you give any other example of convergence?

The points $\frac{1}{kx}$ have null Lebesgue measure in $(0,1)$.

Indeed, so you have non-convergence for almost all $x \in (0,1)$

Yes, but I'm looking for a subsequence $n_j$.

Your title does not say that.  And I doubt that there is a single subsequence $n_j$ where $\sin (n_j/x)$ converges for almost all $x\in (0,1)$.

A stronger conclusion holds. Namely $\sin(n/x)$ does not admit a subsequence convergent a.e.
Substitute $t={1\over x}.$ Then $t>1.$ For $n\neq m$ we have $$\int\limits_\pi^{3\pi}[\sin(nt)-\sin(mt)]^2\,dt= 2\pi
$$
Assume $\sin(n_kt)\to f(t)$ a.e. In particular it is convergent a.e. on $[\pi,3\pi].$
Applying $(*)$ for $n=n_k,$ $m=n_{k+1}$ and letting $k\to\infty$ gives $0=2\pi,$ a contradiction.
Remark It is crucial that $f_n(t)=\sin(nt)$ are bounded. Then by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem we can exchange the order of the limit and the integral.
The question can be generalized by considering the sequence $\sin(a_nt)$ where $a_n\to \infty. $ WLOG (by taking a subsequence) we may assume that $a_{n+1}-a_n\to \infty.$ Observe that for any $0< a< b$ we have $$\left |\int\limits_a^b\cos kt\,dt\right |={1\over k}|\sin kb-\sin ka|\le {2\over k}\quad (*)$$
Furthermore $$[\sin(a_{n+1}t)-\sin(a_nt)]^2\\ =1-{1\over 2}\cos(2a_{n+1}t)-{1\over 2}\cos(2a_{n}t)\\ +\cos((a_{n+1}+a_n)t)-\cos((a_{n+1}-a_n)t)$$ Integrating over $[a,b]$ and taking the limit with $n\to \infty$, in view of $(*)$, gives $b-a.$ Now we can apply the reasoning from the first part of this answer and conclude that $\sin(a_nt)$ is not convergent a.e. on $[a,b].$

Why the integral  identity implies that cannot exists a subsequence? Let $f(x)=n\mathbb{1}{(0,1/n^2)}$ for example. Of course$ |f|{L^2}=1$, but $f_n\to0$ a.e.

There is no contradiction with your example as $\sin (nx)$ are bounded unlike $f_n$ in your comment. In my case I may rely on the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. But for your $f_n$ it is not available.

You are right! I think that your integral is on $(1,+\infty)$ and not on an interval, so you cannot use Lebesgue convergence thm. Or am I wrong?

My integral is on subinterval $[\pi,3\pi].$ The proof shows that any subsequence does not converge to a constant on this subinterval. Hence neither on $(1,\infty).$ Besides the functions are periodic with period $2\pi.$

Perfect, you answer is very clear! Another question: if we suppose that $n\in\mathbb{R}_+$ how we can conclude that we cannot have convergence? I think that the fact is that $\sin(nx)$ span the whole interval $(-1,1)$ as $n\to+\infty$.

Do you mean a sequence $a_n\to\infty$ of real numbers and $\sin(a_n/x)$ ?

yes. I think that the same result holds.
